# Can I define common dependencies in a file, and import that in commonJS?

Tags: node.js, commonjs

I've got several build tasks that require the same dependencies. It is quite a chore to keep both dependency lists up to date, so I was wondering: is there a way to define dependencies that are shared and then import them for both build tasks?

Say I require the `glob` module for both files. Can I do:

```
// shared.js
var glob = require('glob');

module.exports = something
```

And then import `shared.js` in both files to get those dependencies?

Comment: Probably yes, but really hard to understand your question. Please try to be clear

Comment: @Amit If I have a file `build.js` and `watch.js`, which both need the same npm dependencies, can I define all the dependencies a single time and import that somehow? So that I don't have to do the exact same require's for both `build.js` and `watch.js`?

Comment: I think it basically boils down to whether modules have access to the dependencies of imported modules. Which I think they don't because the aim is to isolate each module? Maybe there's a module on npm that provides this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll split my answer to 2 parts: Technical & Personal opinion.

#### Technical

You can do that quite easily.

*shared.js*

```
module.exports = {
  a: require('a'),
  b: require('b')
  // and as long as required...
}
```

*build.js*

```
var shared = require('shared')
// and if you'd like...
var a = shared.a
var b = shared.b
```

#### Personal opinion

I don't think it's a good idea as the `require ()` syntax is not that verbose and definitely not complicated. The downside will be that you'll likely find that your shared module is utilized in a way that does import more than each and every module really needs. Also it has a negative impact on readability, since seeing `shared.a` is significantly less readable than `var a = require('specific-path/a')`